# Sending clicked element to js from html list

Tags: javascript, html, angular

In my HTML, I have a list of elements. And a js method is called when user clicks on any of this element. Elements vary in terms of class set to them.

I am trying to send clicked element to js function making us of  'this':

```
(click)="onClick(my_string, this)"
```

But it turns out that instead of individual element in list, a parent element is send.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Angular? If so, please tag it. A [mcve] would be great

Comment: The HTML and JS part is missing in this question which would greatly help us in debugging

Answer (score 1):

If you send `$event` you can get the clicked element

```
(click)="onClick(my_string, $event)"
```

On your component you can get the source element

```
onClick(myString, event) {
  let target = event.target || event.srcElement || event.currentTarget;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the `$event` object and in the function use `event.target` to get the element from which event is triggered. There is no need to add `onclick` to each of the element. Instead add it to the parent and delegate the event

HTML

```
<ul (click)="onClick($event)">
  <li class="first"> First Element </li>
  <li class="second"> Second Element </li>
  <li class="third"> Third Element </li>
  <li class="fourth"> Fourth Element </li>
  <li class="fifth"> Fifth Element </li>
</ul>
```

component.js

```
onClick(event) {
    console.log(event.target)
  }
```

Here is the [full code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g4npbc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)